# Is there Python 3 module to read .dbf files written by ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dbf, python-3

I would like to know whether there are Python 3.x-compatible (preferably Python 3.3) modules to read the kind of .dbf files produced by ArcGIS for Desktop.

All the modules I found were only compatible with Python 2.x. I may have missed something, but I really couldn't find any which was compatible with Python 3.x.

Comment: Recognize that ArcGIS does not officially support Python 3.x (as of ArcGIS 10.1).  [The final release of 10.1 includes Python 2.7.2](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/24523-Python-version-10.1).

Comment: @RyanDalton Actually, I just need to import some big bases of legacy ArcGIS-produced `.dbf` and will not need to use ArcGIS anymore.

Comment: PRO supports py3+ not arcmap.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As all Python programmers, I will

- first see the [Python package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=search&term=dbf&submit=search) for dbf files (it is specified if they are not compatible with Python 3 or Python 2). [dbfread](https://github.com/olemb/dbfread), for example, works with Python 2.x and Python 3.x.
- a geospatial modules like [GDAL/OGR](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GDAL/1.9.1) can be used but it needs to be compiled (Linux, Mac OS X). For the Windows users, Christoph Gohlke provides the [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) with [GDAL/OGR](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#gdal) (Python 2.x and Python 3.x)
- and a pure Python geospatial module like [Pyshp](http://code.google.com/p/pyshp/) (Python 2.x or 3.x) can also read dbf files
- and finally, If you know the structure of a dbf file (
  [Data File Header Structure for the
  dBASE Version 7 Table File](http://www.dbase.com/Knowledgebase/INT/db7_file_fmt.htm)
  , for example), it is not complicated to program a reader in pure Python with the [struct](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/struct.html) module

Comment: Well, GDAL might be a little bit too much just for reading such files. But thank you anyway, I had not found `dbfread` before but it worls fine :)

Answer (score 2):

I adapted this function for python 2,7 to python 3,x, works for me, but no warranty ... :)

```
def dbfreader(f): #Found on http://code.activestate.com/recipes/362715-dbf-
reader-and-writer/ - by Raymond Hettinger
"""Returns an iterator over records in a Xbase DBF file.

The first row returned contains the field names.
The second row contains field specs: (type, size, decimal places).
Subsequent rows contain the data records.
If a record is marked as deleted, it is skipped.

File should be opened for binary reads.
Adapted for python 3,5 20-09-2017
"""
# See DBF format spec at:
#     http://www.pgts.com.au/download/public/xbase.htm#DBF_STRUCT

numrec, lenheader = struct.unpack('<xxxxLH22x', f.read(32))
numfields = (lenheader - 33) // 32

fields = []
for fieldno in range(numfields): #PYTHON3
    name, typ, size, deci = struct.unpack('<11sc4xBB14x', f.read(32))
    name=name.decode('utf-8') #PYTHON3
    typ=typ.decode('utf-8') #PYTHON3
    name = name.replace('\0', '')       # eliminate NULs from string
    fields.append((name, typ, size, deci))
yield [field[0] for field in fields]
yield [tuple(field[1:]) for field in fields]

terminator = f.read(1)
terminator=terminator.decode('utf-8') #PYTHON3
assert terminator == '\r'

fields.insert(0, ('DeletionFlag', 'C', 1, 0))
fmt = ''.join(['%ds' % fieldinfo[2] for fieldinfo in fields])
fmtsiz = struct.calcsize(fmt)
for i in range(numrec):
    recordb = struct.unpack(fmt, f.read(fmtsiz))
    record=[]
    for j in range(0,len(recordb)):
        record.append(recordb[j].decode('utf-8')) #PYTHON3
    if record[0] != ' ':
        continue                        # deleted record
    result = []
    for (name, typ, size, deci), value in zip(fields, record):
        if name == 'DeletionFlag':
            continue
        if typ == "N":
            value = value.replace('\0', '').lstrip()
            if (value == '') or "*" in value:
                value = -99
            elif deci:
                value = decimal.Decimal(value)
            else:
                value = int(value)
        elif typ == 'D':
            y, m, d = int(value[:4]), int(value[4:6]), int(value[6:8])
            value = datetime.date(y, m, d)
        elif typ == 'L':
            value = (value in 'YyTt' and 'T') or (value in 'NnFf' and 'F') or '?'
        elif typ == 'F':
            value = float(value)
        result.append(value)
    yield result
```

Answer (score 1):

[Pyshp](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp) is the library you are looking for. It's well documented, step by step. Personally have found it great after osgeo ogr.

Answer (score 0):

[Geopandas](http://geopandas.org/) is definately the way to go! Objects are brought in pandas like structure. Super easy to use + you can run all the typical geospatial operations if needed.

```
# just the dbf
dbf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame.from_file(u"./name.shp")
# whole shapefile
shp  = geopandas.read_file(u"./name.shp")
```

Comment: I would expect the dbf call to have a faster run time than the whole shapefile, but I'm seeing no difference.

Comment: The question asks for how to read the `.dbf` file, but your example points to a `.shp` file. Maybe your answer can include why this is the same thing?

Comment: .dbf files are part of a relational database that always include a .shp .proj and a few other files that make up a "shapefile"

Comment: WARNING: geopandas relies on GDAL and fiona, both of which are compiled and can introduce complications with deploying to the cloud or working with different platforms.

Comment: Gotta disagree. The cloud runs on Linux where compiling is the norm, installing gdal etc is pretty trivial at this point. The only problem with scale/cloud is anything ESRI.